# Project Euler #8: Using numpy to calculate products of sublists returns negative values

Tags: python, numpy, math

I attempted to solve Project Euler #8: Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product.

I broke down a list of integers into sublists of equal lengths of 13 and calculated the product of each sublist to find the max value. However, using numpy.prod vs math.prod provided me with different answers (with math.prod being the correct one). Upon closer examination starting from an index of 88 numpy.prod started returning negative values:

numpy:

```py
[..., 78382080, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 371589120, -1322254336, 1857945600, -1817706496, 1651507200, 412876800, 294912000, ...]
```

math:

```py
[..., 78382080, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 371589120, 2972712960, 1857945600, 2477260800, 1651507200, 412876800, 294912000, ...]
```

I am unsure why this is happening, and I was unable to find anything in the numpy documentation.

**Code**:

p008_num.txt:

```
73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
```

```py
import numpy
import math

f1 = open("p008_num.txt", "r").read()
n_list = list(map(int, list(f1)))
list_of_lists = [n_list[i:i+13] for i in range(len(n_list)-13)]

multi_list = [numpy.prod(num) for num in list_of_lists]
multi_list_1 = [math.prod(num) for num in list_of_lists]
# 23514624000

print("max multi_list:", max(multi_list))
print("max multi_list_1:", max(multi_list_1))
```

Output :

```
max multi_list: 2091059712
max multi_list_1: 23514624000
```

Answer (score 2):

By default `numpy.prod()` function assumes the input is 32 bit integer so it outputs a 32 bit integer but the maximum possible product in your case is 9^13 which is greater than the maximum 32 bit integer so you need to mention `dtype` as `numpy.int64` in `numpy.prod()` function. This way -

```py
multi_list = [numpy.prod(num, dtype=numpy.int64) for num in list_of_lists]
```